# Set parameter on a do while expressions

Tags: php

So I have the following method inside my class:

```
    public function getBlobs(string $container, int $max) : array
    {
        try {
            $blobMeta = [];
            $blobOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();

            // Set the max results at 5000 (Default: 5000)
            $blobOptions->setMaxResults($max);

            do {
                // Grab the defined container
                $blob_list = $this->connect()->listBlobs($container, $blobOptions);

                // Loop through all the
                foreach ($blob_list->getBlobs() as $blob) {
                    $blobMeta[] = [
                        'name' => $blob->getName(),
                        'url' => $blob->getUrl(),
                    ];
                }
                $blobOptions->setContinuationToken($blob_list->getContinuationToken());

            } while ($blob_list->getContinuationToken());

            return $blobMeta;
        } catch (ServiceException $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

**Then I'm calling it like this**:

```
$blobs = $test2->getBlobs('userpictures', 20);
var_dump($blobs);
```

---

**Problem**:

How would I be able to pass in a parameter so that I can call it like this:

```
$blobs = $test2->getBlobs('userpictures');
var_dump($blobs);
```

If I don't pass in a $max param, I'd like to not set a param and it'll be defined as 0 default and the continuousToken will execute on the do while.

```
$blobs = $test2->getBlobs('userpictures', 20);
var_dump($blobs);
```

If I pass in a second param, I'd like the continousToken not to execute.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Answer (score 0):

There is probably multiple way to do it, I will give you an exemple of how you could achieve this kind of behaviour:

First, the parameters of the method, like any method, can have default value :

```
public function getBlobs(string $container, int $max = -1) : array
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

So you could now call either `$test2->getBlobs('userpictures');` or `$test2->getBlobs('userpictures', 123);`.

Just remember that default parameters have to be at the end (for now).

Then you can just check if the parameter is set to default or to any value to enter or not in your `do {} while`:

```
if ($max >= 0) do {}
  while ($blob_list->getContinuationToken());
```

So the condition would be never true if the second parameter is not set.